# ARCore – What is the difference between WorldScale and LocalScale?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to resize my AR models, I'm working with models the size of buildings.

I managed to resize my model using worldscale and localscale but what exactly is the difference and when should I use worldscale to enlarge my model and when to use localscale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Scaling locally a single object

In local space, all operations on the model (translation, rotation and scaling) are performed relative to the Pivot Point of the model.

Official Google ARCore developer documentation [says](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node#setLocalScale(com.google.ar.sceneform.math.Vector3)):

```
public void setLocalScale (Vector3 scale)
```

> Sets the scale of this node relative to its ***parent*** (local-space). If `isTopLevel()` is true, then this is the same as `setWorldScale(Vector3)`.

Here's how it looks like in a real code:

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

TransformableNode n = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
n.setRenderable(modelRenderable);

n.getScaleController().setMinScale(1.74f);
n.getScaleController().setMaxScale(1.75f);

// Set Node's local scale before setting its Parent
n.setLocalScale(new Vector3(1.23f, 1.23f, 1.23f));

n.setParent(anchorNode);
```

### Scaling locally multiple objects

When multiple selected objects are simultaneously scaled locally (using `setLocalScale`), then each of them will be scaled relative to the position of its own pivot point.

However, if you simultaneously scale all these selected objects globally (using `setWorldScale`), they will be scaled relative to one resulting pivot point of The World.

Here's a visual representation of local and world scale:

[image]

World Scale:

[image]

Local Scale:

[image]